# Python import of firebase module causes program to loop unexpectedly

Tags: python, firebase

So, using the python-firebase pip module, the following code:

```
from firebase import firebase

print 'test'
```

Causes the following output:

```
test
test
test
test
test
```

Commenting out the import, or importing any other modules, causes test to be printed only once as expected.  This is happening on my 2 windows machines at home, with different version of python.  My linux boxes at work are not showing this behavior.  Extremely weird.  Anybody know what could possibly be going on?

Answer (score 0):

The pip install of firebase hasnt been updated and has some bugs in it. Take the latest version from [Github](https://github.com/ozgur/python-firebase) you should be fine after using this version.

There is a very good blog post on getting started with this python-firebase here [burhan.io](http://burhan.io/flask-web-api-with-firebase/) check it out :-)

V